# Regex to remove footer text with line breaks

Tags: c#, regex

I am hoping this is quite simple... I am trying to remove a footer from a block of text using a regular expression, this includes the two initial line breaks which is where my problem lies.

```
    Message body blah blah balh
    {Line Break}
    {Line Break}
    ----------------------------------
    Custom footer text
```

I have been experimenting with variations of `/\?(\r\n)(\r\n)([-{34}])/.*` but nothing is working.

Comment: `[-{34}]` should be simply `-{34}`. `[-{34}]` means "-" or "{" or "3" or "4" or "}". And what is `\?` and `.*` at the end?

Comment: Thanks - those are some really good pointers. the .* was trying to get everything after!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a test and this works:

```
[\r\n]*-{34}[\w\s\n\r]*
```

Here's the code:

```
var input = @"Message body blah blah balh


----------------------------------
Custom footer text";

var pattern = @"[\r\n]*-{34}[\w\s\n\r]*";
var clean = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "", RegexOptions.Multiline);

Console.WriteLine(clean);
```

The output is the expected one:

```
Message body blah blah balh
```

---

There were several problems with the initial approach. Some of them were pointed out by [abc667](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1833932/abc667) in the comment above.

Here are two others:

- when you do `(\r\n)`, you are expecting the exact character sequence CR, LF. In some operating systems however, a line break can be represented by only a `\n` (LF). To make the pattern work for both cases, you could use a character class, like so: `[\r\n]*`. This means: *"all the sequence of `\n` and/or `\r` characters you can find, in any order"*.
- the dot (`.`) matches any single character except \n (see [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)). In some regex flavours it may also match newlines under special conditions (see "(dot)" [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)), but not in .NET. This is why I replaced the `.*` that was supposed to match everything after the dotted line with `[\w\s\r\n]*` that will match any word characters, space characters, CR and LF.